# WolframClient Converting Output Of Solve To Sympy

Tags: python, wolfram-client

I'm trying to convert the output of WolframClient to Python. Here's a toy example:

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr

def get_session():
    session = WolframLanguageSession()
    session.evaluate(wlexpr('Range[5]')) #warmup
    return session

session = get_session()
print(session.evaluate("Solve[a[0]==5/3,a[0]]]"))
```

Giving

```
((Rule[Global`a[0], Rational[5, 3]],),)
```

I'm hoping to instead get something simpler (a string is sufficient):

```
"a[0] = 5/3"
```

*Motivation:*

Ideally I'd like to port the output of mathematica to Sympy. I've tried Sympy's Mathematica parser, but it doesn't recognize any of the "non-whitelisted" expressions such as `Rational[5,3]`. I've tried using Mathematica's `InputForm` function but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You may make a PR to sympy's repo, and add the support to `Rational`.

Answer (score 4):

One way to get the form you want is to apply `ToString` and `StringForm`.  For this particular example, `Numerator` and `Denominator` are also used.

```
print(session.evaluate("""
  sol = Values@First@Flatten@Solve[a[0] == 5/3, a[0]];
  ToString@StringForm["a[0] = `1`/`2`", Numerator[#], Denominator[#]] & @sol
  """))

(*  a[0] = 5/3  *)
```

Other forms can be obtained with `ToString` and `StringJoin` (`<>`)

```
print(session.evaluate("""
  sol = N@Values@First@Flatten@Solve[a[0] == 5/3, a[0]];
  "a[0] = " <> ToString[sol] """))

(*  a[0] = 1.66667  *)
```

In either case the Python return type is `str`, as

```
retval = session.evaluate("""
  sol = N@Values@First@Flatten@Solve[a[0] == 5/3, a[0]];
  "a[0] = " <> ToString[sol] """)

type(retval)

(*  str  *)
```

If you want the Python return type to be `float`, just use `N`

```
retval = session.evaluate("""
  N@Values@First@Flatten@Solve[a[0] == 5/3, a[0]] """)

type(retval)

(*  float  *)
```